# From HL7 standard, what is the default value for the component PID.3.5?

Tags: hl7

Starting from the below HL7 message, I would to know which is the default value for the component PID.3.5 in case it is missing in the message for evaluating correctly the component PID.3.1.

If it missing, the component PID.3.1 is always a "PI"?

Thanks at all.

```
MSH|^~\&|SAP||JCAPS||20191127122003||ADT^A28|0000032299874572|P|2.5
EVN||20191127122003
PID|||706990290056^^^SAP||ARMANDOLA&&&&ARMANDOLA^GIOVANNI^^^SIG.^""||19621108|M|||^^VOGHERA^^^IT^BDL^^018182~&STRADA ROSMAGNA 26^""^VOGHERA^PV^27058^IT^L^^018182^^^^20191127||^ORN^^^^^^^^^^3887959825~^NET^^""|||6||||||||||IT^^100^Italiana|||""||||20190902
PD1|||ATS DI PAVIA^^^^^^ASLR^^^030328||||||||""^^HSR^0001^IRCCS San Raffaele^HSR
NK1|1||SEL|&""^^""^^""^IT^^^""|^ORN^^^^^^^^^^""~^NET^^""|||""|||12||""^^""
NK1|2|ARMANDOLA^""||&STRADA ROSMAGNA 26^^VOGHERA^^27058^IT^^^018182|^ORN^^^^^^^^^^3887959825~^NET^^""
NK1|3|""^""
NK1|4||SEL|||||19900101||||||||||||||P^Consenso Rilasciato|||||||||||OSR-DSDP^^^^^^19900101
NK1|5||SEL|||||20190902||||||||||||||P^Consenso Rilasciato|||||||||||OSR-TD^^^^^^20190902
NK1|6||SEL|||||20190902||||||||||||||N^Consenso Negato|||||||||||OSR-MI^^^^^^20190902
NK1|7||SEL|||||20190902||||||||||||||A^Consenso Assente|||||||||||OSR-DC^^^^^^20190902
NK1|8||SEL|||||20190902||||||||||||||A^Consenso Assente|||||||||||OSR-RD^^^^^^20190902
PV1||N
PV2||||||||||||||||||||||||ATTIVO
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no default value. Its just not stated, and you have to consult local documentation (if available)

Comment: Hi @Grahame Grieve. Thanks for your response. What do you mean for local documentation? Maybe, the technical specification from the HIS that will send the message? Thanks again.